# How can I add a padding to my page scroll function and keep the navigation elements highlight at the right time?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a padding to my page scroll function. 
Page Example: http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/

The script:

```
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
        } else {
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
        }
    });

    //jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
    $(function() {
        $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
            var $anchor = $(this);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
            }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

I changed this line and now it is working very well:

```
scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-50
```

But now my problem is `a.page-scroll` in the navigation menu does not highlight at the right time and I do not now how to solve this problem.

---

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Scrolling Nav - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<!-- The #page-top ID is part of the scrolling feature - the data-spy and data-target are part of the built-in Bootstrap scrollspy function -->

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Intro Section -->
    <section id="intro" class="intro-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Scrolling Nav</h1>
                    <p><strong>Usage Instructions:</strong> Make sure to include the <code>scrolling-nav.js</code>, <code>jquery.easing.min.js</code>, and <code>scrolling-nav.css</code> files. To make a link smooth scroll to another section on the page, give the link the <code>.page-scroll</code> class and set the link target to a corresponding ID on the page.</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-default page-scroll" href="#about">Click Me to Scroll Down!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about" class="about-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>About Section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Services Section -->
    <section id="services" class="services-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Services Section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact" class="contact-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Contact Section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

also change this line

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top" data-offset="50">
```